# urlstyle, urlfont and newfontfamily interaction

Tags: fonts, xetex, hyperref, fontspec, url

I'm using XeLaTeX and fontspec. I want to change the font (to the courier font) that is shown when using \url.

I don't understand why "\renewcommand\UrlFont{\courierfont}" works but "\urlstyle{\courierfont}" or "\urlstyle{Courier}" don't work. Using \courierfont i get the error "!Missing \endcsname inserted" and "!Extra \endcsname".

output:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newfontfamily{\courierfont}{Courier}

\begin{document}
\url{https://example.com/example}

\urlstyle{\courierfont}
\url{https://example.com/example}

\urlstyle{Courier}
\url{https://example.com/example}

\renewcommand\UrlFont{\courierfont}
\url{https://example.com/example}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just a few predefined URL styles. You need to define a new one, if you so want.

The key is to define the macro `\url@<name>style` that will redefine `\UrlFont`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newfontfamily{\courierfont}{Courier}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\url@courierstyle}{\def\UrlFont{\courierfont}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\url{https://example.com/example}

\urlstyle{courier}
\url{https://example.com/example}

\end{document}
```

[image]